# Google Spreadsheets equivalent of Excel CLEAN() formula

Tags: google-sheets

I've created an Excel file where a non-technical co-worker of mine organizes a bunch of data into rows and columns.

I then have formulas concatenate across those rows and columns and add some HTML tags (`<td>`, `<tr>`).  Then I use the `CLEAN()` function to wrap the result of those concatenations.  I can then copy and paste from that final cell into MailChimp to send out an HTML email newsletter.

I'd prefer to convert the Excel file into a Google Spreadsheet since it keeps a revision history and allows live collaboration.

However, since there is no `CLEAN()` function in Google Spreadsheets, if I copy from my Google Spreadsheet into HTML, there are lots of extra double-quotes that ruin everything.

Anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the output you try to paste?

Comment: I don't want double-quotes added: `" <table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"" width=""645"" class=""couponBoundary"">
    <tr>
        <td width=""130"" class=""couponStoreLogoCell"">
            <div align=""center"">
             <img src=""/images/merchants/756_t.jpg"">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>"`

Comment: I had the same problem as you, but today when I copied the same stuff from the same source, the quotes are just gone. Tested with Notes and XCode (Mac softwares). Today no problem. Maybe Google fixed it... I didn't do any changes. I didn't even know about a CLEAN function.

Comment: In their later comment the OP mentions _"There are no extra double-quotes in the actual contents; they just appear when I copy OUT from the spreadsheet into an HTML file."_ Those unwanted double quotes appear because Google Sheets automatically escapes text that contains **newlines** when copy-pasting. When you run the text through `clean()` or `regexreplace()`, those newlines get weeded out, and no escaping is necessary. The smartest solution would be to modify the formulas that produce the newlines in the first place. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have thought of this sooner: my workaround is File > Publish to the Web.  Now, whenever I edit the worksheets, the published webpage (viewable by my company's employees) automatically updates, and we can copy-and-paste from there.

Answer (score 3):

As of 11-12-2013 the `CLEAN()` function is available in Google Spreadsheet:

- https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267340

I wasn't able to reproduce the results (now and back then, as did @Jonny on the 18th of April) but the `CLEAN()` function should remove the non-printable characters.

See following reference, on how to activate the new Google Spreadsheet:

- https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3541068

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the double-quotes, try wrapping your cell in this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CONCAT(CHAR(34),CHAR(34)),CHAR(34))
```

A1: `<table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"" width=""645"" class=""couponBoundary""> <tr> <td width=""130"" class=""couponStoreLogoCell""> <div align=""center""> <img src=""/images/merchants/756_t.jpg""> </div> </td> </tr> </table>`

B1: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CONCAT(CHAR(34),CHAR(34)),CHAR(34))`

Produces:

`<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="645" class="couponBoundary"> <tr> <td width="130" class="couponStoreLogoCell"> <div align="center"> <img src="/images/merchants/756_t.jpg"> </div> </td> </tr> </table>`

Not the most elegant, but it gets the job done :)

Comment: There are no extra double-quotes in the actual contents; they just appear when I copy OUT from the spreadsheet into an HTML file. In my case, the contents of A1 LOOKS fine (doesn't have double-double-quotes), but when I copy from it and then paste it into an HTML file, it adds unnecessary double-quotes. Thanks though.

Comment: Ahh, got it - which program are you pasting into?

Comment: Notepad, Notepad++, Netbeans, anything. It happens no matter where I paste it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a clean solution, but if you copy, then paste special >> as values somewhere else in your spreadsheet, THEN copy that cell, you will have a perfectly formatted HTML code.