# Copying cells in Google Spreadsheets and pasting into text file adds quotes around each cell

Tags: copy-paste, google-sheets

Copying cells in Google Spreadsheets and pasting into text file (tried with XCode, Notes, Text Edit - the below applies to all) adds quotes around each cell.
How can I avoid those extra quotes? Also, each quote within the text itself has another quote added to it. I just want to copy the contents as are. Is there a hidden "copy plain" feature?

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/33989/29140

Comment: It's similar and or the same yes. The odd thing is that today when I copied the same stuff from the same spreadsheet, the extra quotes are just gone. No problem anymore. Maybe Google fixed it. Or it magically disappeared somehow. Let's hope it does not magically reappear again.

Comment: i notice that it only happens when cells contain newlines and possibly other special characters.  adding the quotes might be done by the program you paste into -- each program may have the ability to convert tabular data into non tabular data as it wishes.  if i paste into Google Keep, i see no quotes, but if i paste into my text editor, i get quotes.  perhaps you can try first pasting into Google Keep, then copy again, and paste into destination program.

Comment: Alexander, please add your comment as an answer, I reproduced the problem and fixed it as you say, the text had newline char.

Answer (score 1):

Copy of a [Comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43143/copying-cells-in-google-spreadsheets-and-pasting-into-text-file-adds-quotes-arou#comment73124_43143) by [Alexander Taylor](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/23984/alexander-taylor) Oct 27 '15 at 22:34 :

> i notice that it only happens when cells contain newlines and possibly other special characters. adding the quotes might be done by the program you paste into -- each program may have the ability to convert tabular data into non tabular data as it wishes. if i paste into Google Keep, i see no quotes, but if i paste into my text editor, i get quotes. perhaps you can try first pasting into Google Keep, then copy again, and paste into destination program.